# GSP tags in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I had the following in the `<head>` of a GSP

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $("button.remove-item").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "${createLink(action: 'remove', controller: 'cart')}",
            type: 'POST'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Notice that I'm using the Grails [createLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) tag to construct the URL that the AJAX request will post to. When I moved this code into `checkout.js` and replaced the block of code above with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'checkout.js')}"></script>
```

the `createLink` tag is no longer evaluated by Grails. So it seems that Grails tags within `<script>` blocks are evaluated, but tags within .js files included by GSPs are not - is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the GSParse plugin to have css and js parsed as a gsp file:

http://nerderg.com/GSParse

http://grails.org/plugin/gsp-arse

Comment: That seems to fit the bill perfectly

Comment: Any solution for grails 3 app?

Answer (score 2):

You are right .js files are not evaluated by grails! but the GSP are! so thats why when u were setting a  tag it was working.
I would suggest you to have a differente approach of how to grab that link! as u are using jquery I would do like this:

```
<input type="button" class="remove-item" data-url="${createLink(action: 'remove', controller: 'cart')}" value="GO" />
```

checkout.js:

```
$("button.remove-item").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        type: 'POST'
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess that would work, but I don't like adding custom attributes to HTML elements

Comment: Custom data attributes are perfectly valid in HTML5, FWIW.